# Integrate $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}.$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Completing the square and letting $t=x+1$, I obtain $$\int\sqrt{(x+1)^2+2} \ dx=\int\sqrt{t^2+2}\ dt.$$

Letting $u=t+\sqrt{t^2+2},$ I get

\begin{array}{lcl}
u-t & = & \sqrt{t^2+2} \\
u^2-2ut+t^2 & = & t^2+2 \\
t & = & \frac{u^2-2}{2u} \\
dt &=&  \frac{u^2+2}{2u^2}du 
\end{array}

Thus the integral becomes

$$F(x)=\int \left(u-\frac{u^2-2}{2u}\right)\left(\frac{u^2+2}{2u^2}\right) \ du = \int \left(\frac{u^2+2}{2u}\right)\left(\frac{u^2+2}{2u^2}\right) \ du =\int\frac{u^4+4u^2+4}{4u^3} \ du.$$

This integrand is nicely divided into

\begin{array}{lcl}
F(x) & = & \frac{1}{4}\int u \ du+\int \frac{1}{u} \ du+\int \frac{1}{u^3}=\frac{u^2}{8}+\ln{|u|}-\frac{1}{2u^2}+C \\
& = &  \frac{(t+\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}{8}+\ln{|t+\sqrt{t^2+2}|}-\frac{1}{2(t+\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}+C \\
\end{array}

And finally in terms of $x$:

$$F(x)=\frac{(x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})^2}{8}+\ln{|x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}|}-\frac{1}{2(x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})^2}+C.$$

The answer in the book is:

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left((x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+2\ln{|x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}|\right)+C.$$

**Can anyone help me identify where I missed what?**

Comment: I couldn't find a mistake by going through your steps. However, your last term in your anti derivative has a term in the denominator, that numerator is a constant. When you multiply that term with its conjugate (squared), the denominator becomes a...$-2$, (ignoring the 1/2 upfront). Now when you combine that result with your first term, maybe you can rhyme both answers.

Comment: That $1/4$ should not have been there anyway, as Randomgirl pointed out

Comment: True, was a typo. But I corrected it now because as random girl said, I continued as if it was a 1.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B1%2Bsqrt%28x^2%2B2x%2B3%29%29^2%2F8-1%2F%282*%28x%2B1%2Bsqrt%28x^2%2B2x%2B3%29%29^2%29

Comment: That link shows that your last term and your first term when combine simplify to the first term on book's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute
\begin{align}
\frac{(t+\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}{8}-\frac{1}{2(t+\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}
&=
\frac{(t+\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}{8}-\frac{(t-\sqrt{t^2+2})^2}{2(t^2-(t^2+2))^2}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{t^2+2t\sqrt{t^2+2}+(t^2+2)-t^2+2t\sqrt{t^2+2}-(t^2+2)}{8}
\\[6px]
&=\frac{t\sqrt{t^2+2}}{2}
\end{align}

Do you see it, now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would work it.

$t = \sqrt 2 \tan \theta\\
dt = \sqrt 2 \sec^2 \theta$

$\int 2\sec^3 \theta\\
\sec\theta\tan\theta + \ln [\sec\theta+\tan\theta]+C\\
\frac {1}{2} t\sqrt {t^2 + 2} + \ln \frac 12 (t+\sqrt{t^2 + 2}+ C\\
\frac {1}{2} (x+1)\sqrt {x^2 + 2x + 3} + \ln [x+1 + \sqrt {x^2 + 2x + 1}]+ C$

Comment: It does work with my substitution as well. The book recommends to do that particular substitution. Thanks for your answer!